# What is the best way to create HOC withAuth in Next.js in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a Next.js app and I'm using `next-auth` package. I'm trying to create a HOC that will wrap around the actual component and will determine if it has session or not. I'm also using eslint. Here's my code:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

type Props = any;

const withAuth = (Component: React.ComponentType<Props>) => {
  const Auth = (props: Props) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { status } = useSession({
      required: true,
      onUnauthenticated() {
        router.push('/welcome/login');
      },
    });

    if (status === 'loading') {
      return 'Loading ...';
    }

    return <Component {...props} />;
  };
  return Auth;
};

export default withAuth;
```

Eslint gives me a warning about me using type `any`. I tried to change those two lines to where I'm using a generic type:

```
const withAuth = <P extends {}>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) => {
  const Auth = (props: P) => {
```

But now it gives me an error:

```
Error: Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value".
- If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `object` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "any value", you probably want `unknown` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "empty object", you probably want `Record<string, never>` instead.
- If you really want a type meaning "any non-nullish value", you probably want `NonNullable<unknown>` instead.  @typescript-eslint/ban-types
```

What is the best way to write a HOC when we have to pass a component as props? And I don't know what kind of component it will be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, TypeScript advises against using `{}` as a generic type constraint because it does not impose any type checking constraints, so it's essentially as lax as using `any`.

You can use `unknown` or `Record<string, unknown>` for a better type safety and also ESLint errors won't pop up.

These types basically assume that you don't know what shape this object will take, but it won't be `null` or `undefined`, making it flexible enough to wrap any component.

So in your case:

```js
const withAuth = <P extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.FC<P> => {
  const Auth: React.FC<P> = (props) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { status } = useSession({
      required: true,
      onUnauthenticated() {
        router.push('/welcome/login');
      },
    });

    if (status === 'loading') {
      return 'Loading ...';
    }

    return <Component {...props} />;
  };

  return Auth;
};

export default withAuth;
```

So here, the props parameter is not of type `any` but of type `P`, which is a generic type that we've constrained to `Record<string, unknown>`.

Answer (score 0):

To create a Higher-Order Component (HOC) with authentication in Next.js using TypeScript, you can define a generic type for the component props and use that type throughout your code. Here's an example of how you can rewrite your `withAuth` HOC:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { ComponentType, ReactElement } from 'react';

type AuthProps = {
  // Define any additional props that the authenticated component may need here.
};

type WithAuthProps = {
  // Define the common props shared by all components wrapped by withAuth.
};

// Define the withAuth HOC
const withAuth =
  <P extends WithAuthProps>(
    WrappedComponent: ComponentType<P>
  ): ComponentType<P> =>
  (props: P): ReactElement => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { status } = useSession({
      required: true,
      onUnauthenticated() {
        router.push('/welcome/login');
      },
    });

    if (status === 'loading') {
      return <div>Loading ...</div>;
    }

    // Pass any additional props required by the wrapped component
    // to ensure type safety.
    const authProps: AuthProps = {
      // Define your authentication-related props here if needed.
    };

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} {...authProps} />;
  };

export default withAuth;
```